# Настройка htaccess для использования автоподдоменов

Tags: .htaccess, поддомены

Задача:

Есть сайт **gid28.ru**. Нужно сделать чтобы по url:

1. **blagoveshchensk.gid28.ru** - открывался url `www.gid28.ru/city/blagoveshchensk`, ну или `www.gid28.ru/city/28`, например.
2. **uniorextrim.gid28.ru** - открывался url `www.gid28.ru/promo/firma/969`, ну или `www.gid28.ru/promo`, а уже саму фирму, я так понимаю, придется брать из поддомена. Хотя, наверное, можно же как-то и, используя это: `uniorextrim.gid28.ru`, получить `www.gid28.ru/promo/firm/uniorextrim`?
3. **map.gid28.ru** - открывался url `map.gid28.ru` (Этот поддомен создан вручную через панель управления хостингом)

Скину 500р на webmoney за действительно грамотный ответ и решение данной задачи.

### 28.03.2014г

Итак до чего я дошел...
Вот запись файла `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gid28.ru
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.gid28.ru/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?q=$0


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.gid28\.ru$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.gid28\.ru$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdomains/index\.php
```

Теперь трудность заключается в том, что основной домен у меня с `WWW`. Не могу сообразить, как прописать регулярку, чтобы `www.gid28.ru` не перенаправлять, а `subdomain.gid28.ru` или `www.subdomain.gid28.ru` перенаправлять.
Или может быть стоит за основной домен взять url без `www`?

Еще не совсем догнал зачем нужны флаги (например [l,QSA] и т.д.)

Comment: Чтобы домен www.site.ru не перенаправлялся я сделал. Теперь остался последний вопрос. Почему у меня www.sub.site.ru перенаправляет правильно, а sub.site.ru не перенаправляет. В чем проблема может быть?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.gid28.ru [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).gid28.ru [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdomains/index\.php
```

Отвечаю почему у меня www.sub.site.ru работал нормально, а sub.site.ru не работал. Когда я создавал домен, я указал, что поддомены находятся в поддиректории домена. Соответственно в Nginx была запись которая все url типа sub.site.ru отправляла в корень_сайта/sub. Вот этого то я и не учел, а так все работает.